# Setting/Accessing Multi-dimensional array from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, multidimensional-array, nsuserdefaults

I'm have a little bit of trouble storing and accessing a multidimensional array from NSUserDefault. Any help would be appreciated. The error I get when I run this code is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'"

```
//To create, add values to and store arrays
multiArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
multiArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray array], [NSMutableArray array], [NSMutableArray array], nil];

[[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:number1]];
[[multiArray objectAtIndex:1] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:number2]];
[[multiArray objectAtIndex:2] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:number3]];
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[standardUserDefaults setObject:multiArray forKey:@"multiArray"];
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];

//To access the array
NSArray *multiArrayCopy = [[NSArray alloc] init];
multiArrayCopy = [[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"multiArray"] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"array count is %i", [[multiArrayCopy objectAtIndex:2] count]);
Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[multiArrayCopy objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]];
Label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[multiArrayCopy objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0]];
Label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[multiArrayCopy objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: and "does not work" means what? And just to let you know your code works for me.

Comment: I should have been more specific, the actual error I get has been included in the question.

Comment: and you are sure it's this code that crashes? As said, I did run this code, and it worked. I guess it's in the part that you omitted. The part of the code that tries to mutate the array you got back from NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because [NSMutableArray array] is a class method of NSArray that returns an empty (non-mutable) array. Remember that NSMutableArray is a sub-class of NSArray. Try creating NSMutableArray list, thusly:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

multiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
multiArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mutableArray0, mutableArray1, mutableArray2, nil];
```

Also, I think multiArray should be NSMutableArray as well. Try this to see if the error goes away.

If it does not work, try breaking apart the logic to the simplest elements. Can you save and get back single dimensional array with your objects? That is, what happens if you do the following?

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArray0 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber]];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:mutableArray0 forKey:@"myMutableArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When you get that working, then try nesting it into another mutable array, thusly:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArray0 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber]];

NSMutableArray *multiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[multiArray addObject:mutableArray0]; 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:multiArray forKey:@"myMutableArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I did add what you suggested but the error remains. In the above code that I originally posted, when I comment out "[standardUserDefaults setObject:multiArray forKey:@"multiArray"];" the program does not crash (although NSUserDefault does not work), I'm thinking it has something to do with adding an NSArray of MSMutableArrays to NSUserDefaults and the program getting confused??

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, I don't think that you can save NSArray to NSUserDefaults. It should be NSMutableArray.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the fact that multiArray should be NSMutableArray.

Comment: I'm sure you can save a mutable array into NSUserDefaults but when you read it back from NSUserDefaults it will be immutable. You then have to make a mutable copy to work with. When you're finished manipulating the copy you can save the copy back to NSUserDefaults.  Having said that, I've never done that with a multidimmensional array.